# How to improve python threading by using locks?

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi I want to calculated the summation of integers from 1 to N by using threading to speed up. Thus I wrote:

```
import threading

N = int(input())
sum = 0
i = 1
lock = threading.Lock()
def thread_worker():
    global sum
    global i
    lock.acquire() 
    sum += i
    i += 1
    lock.release() 

for j in range(N):
    w = threading.Thread(target = thread_worker)
    w.start()
```

Because I don't want to mess up my variable i, I used the lock function. However the speed of code is not improved since only one thread can access the shared variable at a time.
So I want to know is there anyway I can improve the threading runtime? Will adding more variables and locks be helpful?

---

Thanks!

Comment: threading cpu bottleneck tasks in python encounter the GIL and don't actually really run in parallel unlike how you'd expect at first. You may want to consider other alternatives, in general terms, parallel processing, or code optimization. Here specifically, sum upto n can be calculated by a simple formula for summation upto n digits.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your question deserves two answers:

- How to use threading in the right way.
- One for how to speed up the summation of integers between 1 and N.

### How to use threading

There is always some overhead to threading: Creating threads, locking, etc. Even if this overhead is really small, some overhead will remain. This means that threading is only worth it, if each thread has some significant work to be done. Your function does almost nothing inside the `lock.acquire()/release()`. Threads would work, if you were doing some more complicated work there. But you are using the lock function correctly -- this is just not a good problem for threading.

## Fast Summation of 1..N

### Measure, Measure, Measure

I'm running Python 3.7, and have `pytest-benchmark` 3.2.2 installed. Pytest-benchmark runs a function for you an appropriate number of times, and reports statistics on the runtime.

```
import threading
import pytest


def compute_variant1(N: int) -> int:
    global sum_
    global i
    sum_ = 0
    i = 1
    lock = threading.Lock()
    def thread_worker():
        global sum_
        global i
        lock.acquire()
        sum_ += i
        i += 1
        lock.release()

    threads = []
    for j in range(N):
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target = thread_worker))
        threads[-1].start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    return sum_

@pytest.mark.parametrize("func", [
    compute_variant1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("N,expected", [(10, 55), (30, 465), (100, 5050)])
def test_var1(benchmark, func, N, expected):
    result = benchmark(func, N=N )
    assert result == expected
```

Run this with: `py.test --benchmark-histogram=bench` And open the generated `bench.svg` It also prints this table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- benchmark: 3 tests -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name (time in us)                               Min                    Max                  Mean                StdDev                Median                 IQR            Outliers         OPS            Rounds  Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_var1[10-55-compute_variant1]          570.0710 (1.0)       4,900.3160 (1.51)       658.8392 (1.0)        270.6056 (1.36)       602.5220 (1.0)       42.6373 (1.0)         19;82  1,517.8209 (1.0)         529           1
test_var1[30-465-compute_variant1]       1,701.2970 (2.98)      3,237.5830 (1.0)      1,879.8490 (2.85)       198.3905 (1.0)      1,802.5160 (2.99)     146.4465 (3.43)        59;43    531.9576 (0.35)        432           1
test_var1[100-5050-compute_variant1]     5,809.7500 (10.19)    13,354.3520 (4.12)     6,698.4778 (10.17)    1,413.1428 (7.12)     6,235.4355 (10.35)    766.0440 (17.97)         6;7    149.2876 (0.10)         74           1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Simpler Algorithms are Faster

Often it is really helpful to compare a fast implementation against the most straightforward one.

The simplest implementation I can think of -- without using Python tricks -- is a simple loop:

```
def compute_variant2(N):
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        sum_ += i
    return sum_
```

Python has a function called `sum()` which takes a list or any *iterable* like `range(N)`:

```
def compute_variant3(N: int) -> int:
    return sum(range(1, N+1))
```

Here are the results (I've removed some columns):

```
------------------------------------------------------- benchmark: 3 tests ------------------------------------------------
Name (time in us)                             Mean              StdDev                Median             Rounds  Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_var1[100-5050-compute_variant2]        4.2328 (1.0)        1.6411 (1.0)          4.1150 (1.0)       163106           1
test_var1[100-5050-compute_variant3]        4.7113 (1.11)       1.6773 (1.02)         4.5560 (1.11)      141744           1
test_var1[100-5050-compute_variant1]    6,404.1856 (>1000.0)  668.2502 (407.21)   6,257.6385 (>1000.0)      106           1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see the `variant1` based on threading is many, many times slower than the sequential implementations.

### Even faster using Mathematics

Carl Friedrich Gauss, when he was a child [1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel#Herkunft_der_Bezeichnung), re-discovered aclose-form solution to our problem: `N * (N + 1) / 2`.

This can be expressed in Python:

```
def compute_variant4(N: int) -> int:
    return N * (N + 1) // 2
```

Let's compare that to the other fast implementations (I'll leave out the first implementation):

[image: Benchmark Results]

And as you can see in the table: The last variant is faster, and importantly **independent of N**.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- benchmark: 12 tests -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name (time in ns)                          Min                     Max                  Mean                StdDev                Median                 IQR              Outliers  OPS (Kops/s)            Rounds  Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var1[10-55-compute_variant4]          162.0100 (1.0)        1,053.6800 (1.0)        170.1799 (1.0)         32.5862 (1.0)        163.7200 (1.0)        8.1800 (1.59)      1135;1225    5,876.1353 (1.0)       58310         100
var1[13-91-compute_variant4]          162.1400 (1.00)       1,354.3200 (1.29)       181.5037 (1.07)        46.2132 (1.42)       176.1800 (1.08)       5.1500 (1.0)      2214;14374    5,509.5296 (0.94)      61452         100
var1[30-465-compute_variant4]         188.8900 (1.17)       1,874.2800 (1.78)       200.4983 (1.18)        40.8533 (1.25)       191.0000 (1.17)       9.8300 (1.91)      1245;1342    4,987.5732 (0.85)      51919         100
var1[100-5050-compute_variant4]       192.9091 (1.19)       5,938.7273 (5.64)       209.0628 (1.23)        75.8845 (2.33)       198.5455 (1.21)      10.9091 (2.12)      1879;4696    4,783.2508 (0.81)     194515          22
var1[10-55-compute_variant2]          676.1000 (4.17)      18,987.8000 (18.02)      719.4231 (4.23)       194.5556 (5.97)       689.0000 (4.21)      34.9000 (6.78)      1447;2199    1,390.0027 (0.24)     125898          10
var1[13-91-compute_variant2]          753.9000 (4.65)      12,103.8000 (11.49)      799.2837 (4.70)       201.3654 (6.18)       766.5000 (4.68)      38.1000 (7.40)      1554;3049    1,251.1203 (0.21)     124441          10
var1[10-55-compute_variant3]        1,021.0000 (6.30)      77,718.8000 (73.76)    1,157.6125 (6.80)       544.1982 (16.70)    1,098.2000 (6.71)      73.0000 (14.17)    3802;12244      863.8469 (0.15)     186672           5
var1[13-91-compute_variant3]        1,127.6000 (6.96)      44,606.4000 (42.33)    1,279.9332 (7.52)       476.7700 (14.63)    1,200.2000 (7.33)      90.0000 (17.48)    4022;21018      781.2908 (0.13)     172147           5
var1[30-465-compute_variant2]       1,304.7500 (8.05)      48,218.5000 (45.76)    1,457.3923 (8.56)       550.7975 (16.90)    1,385.7500 (8.46)      80.2500 (15.58)    3944;22221      686.1570 (0.12)     177086           4
var1[30-465-compute_variant3]       1,738.6667 (10.73)     86,587.3333 (82.18)    1,935.1659 (11.37)      762.7118 (23.41)    1,860.3333 (11.36)    128.6667 (24.98)     2474;6870      516.7516 (0.09)     176773           3
var1[100-5050-compute_variant2]     3,891.0000 (24.02)    181,009.0000 (171.79)   4,218.4608 (24.79)    1,721.8413 (52.84)    3,998.0000 (24.42)    210.0000 (40.78)     1788;2670      237.0533 (0.04)     171881           1
var1[100-5050-compute_variant3]     4,200.0000 (25.92)     76,885.0000 (72.97)    4,516.5853 (26.54)    1,452.5713 (44.58)    4,343.0000 (26.53)    210.0000 (40.78)     1204;2311      221.4062 (0.04)     153587           1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```